# Rust: efficiently store f64 and non-f64

Tags: rust

In rust, is there an efficient way to store a large `Vec<f64>`, which may occasionally contain non-f64. A naive approach:

```rust
enum MaybeNumber {
    Number(f64)
    NonNumber(Box<...>)
}
```

`Vec<MaybeNumber>` will store an entire extra 8 bits to accomodate the enum, resulting in 16 bits per f64.

Comment: "resulting in 16 bits per f64"? Where do the 16bits come from in your example?

Comment: `std::mem::size_of::<MaybeNumber>()`

Comment: If you are looking for a general solution, then I doubt you'll find one. Some cases might be optimized, like if you know non-f64 is rare you can have a separate array for a map of [index => non-f64], but the downside is that you will always have to first check if an index has a value in that map before reading the f64 array.

Comment: @zoran404 You don't necessarily need to check every index individually. e.g. depending on the use case you could determine that the first non-f64 is at index 10000 and then you could read the first 10000 f64's without checking again.

Comment: Yes, that's a god tip for sequential reads, but for random reads you will have to check on every read operation

Comment: You can use NaN boxing if you want to save memory. Other than that, you'll need to specify what exactly you are doing with it (preferably with code) and what you want to be efficient in.

Comment: Array of structs → struct of array is a common optimization. I wonder if there's a similar optimization (and a crate implementing it) where the enum payloads are stored in one array and the discriminants in another. With alignment making `MaybeNumber` 16 bytes (not bits, bytes — 8 for the `f64`/`Box`, 1 for the discriminant, 7 for alignment), this optimization would save roughly 7/16 of the space.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the `NonNumber(Box<...>)` outside the `Vec<f64>` and store a dummy `f64` in its place.

Then you need to maintain a separate data structure which indicates at which indices there are dummy `f64`s and need to be replaced by the `NonNumber` value.

Comment: How is this more efficient than what the OP already tried?

Comment: You have a vector containing only naked `f64` values instead of mostly `Number(f64)` and some `NonNumber(...)`. It is only worth it if the saved overhead of the `f64` values outweigh the additional memory needed for the bookkeeping.

Comment: Yes, but your optimization seems to be negated by the fact that you need to have a separate data structure to store which values are of what kind. And then you have a third array for non-f64.

Comment: The non-f64 you have to store anyway.

Comment: But what data struture do you store the non-f64 with?